# 3-column full screen app layout in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid-layout

I'm creating an admin dashboard for an app, where I need a layout like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                                                               |
|                              NAVBAR                                           |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|        |                                                  |                   |
|   N    |                                                  |                   |
|   A    |                                                  |                   |
|   V    |                                                  |                   |
|   I    |                                                  |                   |
|   G    |                                                  |                   |
|   A    |                                                  |                   |
|   T    |                      MAIN VIEW                   |       SUB         |
|   I    |                                                  |       VIEW        |
|   O    |                                                  |                   |
|   N    |                                                  |                   |
|        |                                                  |                   |
|        |                                                  |                   |
|        |                                                  |                   |
|        |                                                  |                   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The width and height should be 100% of the entire viewport. I tried to do it by fixing the top navbar using `.navbar-fixed-top`, `position: absolute` for the side navigation and fixing the heights for the main and sub views using media queries for different screen sizes. But I am looking for a better, cleaner solution. How can I do it?

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/

Comment: @Morpheus Yes, I have seen this. But the layout I need is a fixed layout, with scrolling inside the main and sub views.

Comment: Set the height and add overflow auto?

Comment: Yes, but then I'd have to change the heights for different screens using media queries. I'm already doing that. But I'm looking for a better approach.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a fairly simple way to accomplish what you want.  The media query allows the height of the nav, main and sub views to go to auto assuming that you want to collapse for xs viewports.

### [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/Bd8JJ381xq#)

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
   height: 100%; 
}
.container-fluid.content {
    padding-top: 50px;
    height: 100%;
}
.container-fluid.content>.row {
    height: 100%;
}    
.mainview, .navview, .subview {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;        
}
.navview, .subview {
    background-color: #eee;        
}         

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .mainview, .navview, .subview {
      height: auto;   
    }
}
```

**Basic HTML Structure:**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid content">
  <!-- Example row of columns -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 navview">
      <h2>Navigation</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7 mainview">
      <h2>Main View</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 subview">
      <h2>Sub View</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a Rails gem called Leather, and it has some components that I added to Bootstrap that might help you create this layout. If you add a .navbar-static-top to the example layout at http://leather.flyoverworks.com/layouts/three_column, it should get you pretty close to what you described.